# Fatal: Could not read password for 'https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to merge the `develop` branch to the `master` branch when building with Azure Pipelines PowerShell task.

But while executing the command `git push`, I'm getting this error:

> Fatal: Could not read password for
>   'https://OrganizationName@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

The code repository is "Azure Repos Git".

```
git checkout -b master
git config --global user.email "xxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx"
git config --global user.name "xxxxx"
git merge origin/develop 
git push origin master
```

After referring some URLs, I've created the Personal Access Token, and modified the push command as `git push https://PAT@dev.azure.com/OrganizationName`, but it's still not working.

Please let me know, if you find a solution for this issue.

Comment: PAT is your solution, what is "it also not worked"? what you got?

Comment: Got the error as "fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:"

Comment: You need to append the team project and the git repo in the url

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to use PAT but in this way:

```
git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}
```

---

Another solution is to "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token" in the job options:

[image: photo]

In the git push use the System.AccessToken:

```
git push https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/......
```

And give push permissions to the build user (in the repo settings):

[image]

Comment: For .yaml build pipelines (currently the default for Azure Pipelines), set the `persistCredentials: true`. See the [Checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) options.

Comment: there is no`contribute` permission in Azure today, what could be an alternate permission ?

Comment: I can see the `Contribute` permissions today..

Comment: In bash pass the _SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to the script as environment variable `env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)` and use it inside the script without the $env prefix, `git ls-remote --exit-code --heads https://$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/<company>/<teamProject>/_git/<repository> refs/heads/<branch>`. That worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me with minor chages while using Bash: `git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/[...]`

Answer (score 9):

Add checkout as the first step:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

Make sure you set the git config

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Make sure to Grant version control permissions to the build service.

1. Go to project settings --> Repositories menu --> Your repository --> Security tab, and grant the following permissions to the `Project Collection Build Service ({your organization})` identity:

- Create branch: Allow
- Contribute: Allow
- Read: Allow
- Create tag: Allow

You should now be able to use git commands without having to manually append the access token to any git commands.

More info see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: This answer need more upvote! thx

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Shayki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56734304/343347), but if you are not running a powershell task use:

```
git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/......
```

I am notably using

- classic pipelines
- an onprem Windows build agent

  - Agent job settings has **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** enabled
- command line task

Answer (score 1):

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  - master
  - your-branch-name-here

pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: "macos-latest"

jobs:
  - job: Perform_Commit_From_CI
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        persistCredentials: true #Important - Persist creds to run further git command
        clean: true
      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: "16.13.2"
        displayName: "Install Node.js"
      - script: |
          git config --global user.email test@gmail.com
          git config --global user.name "Test User"
        displayName: Configure git
      - script: |
          yarn install
          yarn start NAME_OF_THE_SCRIPT_YOU_WANT_TO_EXECUTE
          git add -A
          git commit -m 'Test commit [skip ci]'
          git push origin HEAD:your-branch-name-here 
        displayName: "Test Script"
```

This will work without PAT.

Comment: Something that is important to note with this example is the `[skip ci]` part in the commit message. This will prevent the CI from triggering on the same branch with your push

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to personal access tokens is to use a Git credential helper such as [Git Credential Manager](https://github.comGitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (included in Git for Windows) or [git-credential-azure](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-azure) (included in several Linux distributions). Both support authentication to Azure Repos (dev.azure.com).

> The first time you authenticate, the helper opens a browser window to Microsoft login. Subsequent authentication is non interactive.

Answer (score -3):

The issue might come up because the Azure Repository you are using is a Private one.

Changing the Project visibility to Public solved the issue.

Comment: security wise, this is a bad decision. You should rather fix the root cause instead of loosening up security