# azure pipeline failed "could not read password" - credentials persisted, permissions are set

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my yaml pipeline i want to run maven release. I get this error:

```
[ERROR] Cloning into 'checkout'...
[ERROR] fatal: could not read Password for 'https:********@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Answers suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733922/fatal-could-not-read-password-for-https-organizationnamedev-azure-com-ter) seem not to help. This is the pipeline (see checkout and script):

```
parameters:
- name: releaseVersion
  displayName: release releaseVersion
  type: string
  default: "changeme"
- name: tagName
  displayName: tag name
  type: string
  default: "changeme"
- name: nextVersion
  displayName: next version
  type: string
  default: "changeme"

trigger: none


steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
  fetchDepth: 0
- script: |
    git config user.email "release-pipeline@example.com"
    git config user.name "release-pipleine"
    git fetch --all
    git checkout master 
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    artifactsFeeds: 'Artifacts'
- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'release:clean release:prepare release:perform'
    options: >-  
      --batch-mode
      -DreleaseVersion=${{ parameters.releaseVersion }}
      -DtagName=${{ parameters.tagName }} 
      -DnextVersion=${{ parameters.nextVersion }}
      -Darguments="-Dmaven.deploy.skip=true"
```

Build service has this permissions set

[image]

So how to make this work?

Comment: In which step do you get the error?

Comment: it is in maven step, release:prepare tries to checkout from scm